# TSLint says Expression is always true. (strict-type-predicates) for typeof document !== 'undefined

Tags: typescript

With `strictNullChecks` enabled in `tsconfig.json` I'm now receiving `TSLint says Expression is always true.` (strict-type-predicates) for `typeof document !== 'undefined'`

[image]

Is there a way of rectifying this without silencing it with `tslint:disable-next-line: strict-type-predicates`

I'm assuming the issue is caused by this line in `lib.dom.ts` which does not have the union `| null`.
`declare var document: Document;`

I'm doing SSR so `window` and `document` may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on an SSR project and I've used the 'as' operator to get around this linting rule for the window object, it will work for document as well.

```
const isBrowser = typeof (window as any) !== 'undefined'

export default isBrowser
```